# Visual Basic XMLTextWriter -> No Linebreaks after WriteRaw

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have been trying to get my code to do what I want for the last couple of hours. Not working.

So I have an xml file with several things. In my program, I read this file but I don't need anything. After I made changes the program should save the XML Lines that where readout + the ones not in the same file. This is why I need to read the other part anyway, otherwise, it will get overwritten.

So I decided to just buffer the other parts in a String (actually a List Of, but doesn't matter) with

```
Dim str as String = XmlReader.ReadOuterXml
```

Afterwards, when the file gets saved, I do

```
XmlTextWriter.WriteRaw(str)
```

This is working too, but somehow after the Raw Input my Other Write Functions like

```
XmlTextWriter.WriteStartElement("Change")
XmlTextWriter.WriteAttributeString("test", a.test)
XmlTextWriter.WriteEndElement()
```

wont receive a Line Break and everything is in one line till the end of file, which results in an error or bad input when loading the file again in another instance.

What am I doing wrong and why is that...

Do I need to say XmlTextWriter.EndRaw or something? I don't know, because this one doesn't exist.

Thanks for helping me out

Edit:

My Xml looks like this

```
<main>
   <NodesFromInstance Test="...">
   <NodesFromWriteRaw>
   <NodesFromWriteRaw>
</main>
```

When I do WriteString instead of WriteRaw in the output file is this

```
 &lt;NodesFromWriteRaw FileName="example"&gt;
    &lt;Sub Attrib="" /&gt;
    &lt;Sub Attrib="" /&gt;
  &lt;/NodesFromWriteRaw&gt;
```

instead of < ... >

And when I do WriteString("\n") or something then \n is inside the text. what is happening

Comment: Please note that VBA is ***not*** the same as VB.NET. Please take care when tagging your questions. If you don't, the people who *might* answer will not see them.

Comment: Is the WriteRaw between a WriteStartElement and WriteEndElement? From my quick test it seems when it is not in an element, everything is written on one line and the XML may be incorrect. Also, if you want the raw data escaped, you should use WriteString instead of WriteRaw. The sample here appears to work if you want to take a look: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmltextwriter.writeraw?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @Wiz thanks for your reply. I edited my Post. Indeed my WriteRaw is inside an opened WriteStartElement, because otherwise my xml file would not have a single root node

Comment: Not sure how to reproduce the issue. Can you post a sample piece of code that shows the problem.